# Strip timestamp from the date field in Datatables

Tags: java, javascript, datatables

I am using jquery Datatables plugin. I followed the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190718/jQuery-DataTables-and-J2EE-web-application-integra

I am passing a Date in the JSON object to the datatables plugin. The format from webservice call is like

> "Sat Jan 10 00:08:00 EST 2009"

, I need to strip off the time, EST and the day, I mean it should look something like

> "Jan 10, 2009"

and the column is sorted on the server side. All I need is to strip off the data on the fly on the client side. I am still in the process of learning datatables plugin, I am not sure of implementing this. Experts please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]** Since it looks like the date comes back from the server as a string then you're easiest solution is probably a regular expression.  Try this:

```javascript
function reformatDate(dateStr) {
  var r = /^\w{3}\s+(\w{3})\s+(\d{1,2})\s+.*?(\d{4})$/
    , m = (''+dateStr).match(r);
  return (m) ? m[1]+' '+m[2]+', '+m[3] : dateStr;
}
```

**[Original]** Assuming you are working with an actual [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and you don't want to incur the overhead of a proper JavaScript date wrangling library (such as the excellent [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)) you could format the date like so:

```javascript
var formatDate = (function() {
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  return function(dt) {
    return months[dt.getMonth()] + ' ' + dt.getDate() + ', ' + dt.getFullYear();
  };
})();
formatDate(new Date()); // => "Mar 15, 2012"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with `bServerSide` set to `true` but you might be able to setup column definitions using the `aoColumns` option for the datatable and then apply column rendering via

```
fnRender: function (o, val) {
    parse your date here...
    return newDateString;
}
```